# Fusion this 2 elements

Tags: javascript, pseudocode

I don't know how to fusion this 2 parts of code I tried by ternaire but it didn't work

```
if(marge[i].cas_v)
    dps_cote.push({
        x: i,
        label: cote[i].x,
        y: cote[i].y,
        color: 'green',
        indexLabelFontColor : "red",
        indexLabelFontWeight: "bold",
        indexLabel: marge[i].cas_v.toString()
    });
// CAS_V = NULL
else
    dps_cote.push({
        x: i,
        label: cote[i].x,
        y: cote[i].y,
        color: 'green',
        indexLabelFontColor : "red",
        indexLabelFontWeight: "bold",
        indexLabel: ""
    });
```

Comment: i don't undertand the question... what exactly do you mean by "fusion"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following

```
dps_cote.push({
        x: i,
        label: cote[i].x,
        y: cote[i].y,
        color: 'green',
        indexLabelFontColor : "red",
        indexLabelFontWeight: "bold",
        indexLabel: marge[i].cas_v?marge[i].cas_v.toString():""
    });
```

Comment: Ya today it work I don't know what I did lats time with ternaire. thx

Answer (score 0):

```js
let object = {
    x: i,
    label: cote[i].x,
    y: cote[i].y,
    color: 'green',
    indexLabelFontColor : "red",
    indexLabelFontWeight: "bold",
}
if (marge[i].cas_v) {
    object.indexLabel = marge[i].cas_v.toString();
    dps_cote.push(object);
} else {
    dps_cote.push(object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of the values are defined with arbitrary values in order to provide a working answer.

1. Declare and/or define variables first
2. Then flow controls like conditionals like `if/else if/else` and/or ternary `let x = 0 > y ? z : a`
3. Avoid rewriting code like that object that was defined twice because of `indexLabel` having one of two possible values. If you practice #1 then duplicated code bloat wouldn't be an issue.

Ternaries are different from `if/else if/else` in that it is like an expression:

```
let iL = marge[i].cas_v ? marge[i].cas_v.toString() : "";
/* 
if `marge[i].cas_v` exists then `iL` is `marge[i].cas_v.toString()`
otherwise it is `""`
*/
obj.indexLabel = iL;
// whatever `iL` ends up to be -- its assigned to `obj.indexLabel`
```

---

#### Demo

```js
/* 
if i = 0 then indexLabel: "11"
if i = 1 then indexLabel: "121"
if i = 2 then indexLabel: "14641"
*/
let i = 0;
let cote = [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 0}, {x: 0, y: 1}];
let marge = [{cas_v: 11}, {cas_v: 121}, {cas_v: 14641}];
let dps_cote = [];
let obj = {
  x: i,
  label: cote[i].x,
  y: cote[i].y,
  color: 'green',
  indexLabelFontColor: "red",
  indexLabelFontWeight: "bold",
  indexLabel: ""
};

let iL = marge[i].cas_v ? marge[i].cas_v.toString() : "";

obj.indexLabel = iL;

dps_cote.push(obj);

console.log(dps_cote);
```